# Matlab : how to represent a function submitted to a constraint in 2 variables with absolute values

Tags: matlab, absolute-value, constraints

I would like to plot a function on Matlab

$|x_1+2x_2|+|x_1|$ constraint to $|x_{1}| + |x_{2}| = 1$

I was searching but it has constraint with absolute and with two variables.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to write the new version of the function, and to propose a (slightly) different form for the title.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Given by the Matlab program below :

```
    close all;hold on;box on
    [X1,X2]=meshgrid(-1.5:0.01:1.5);
    Z=abs(X1+2*X2)+abs(X1);
    surf(X1,X2,Z,'edgecolor','none');view([170,60]);
    %
    h=3;z=[0,0,h,h];
    fill3([1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0],z,'g');
    fill3([0,-1,-1,0],[1,0,0,1],z,'r');
    fill3([-1,0,0,-1],[0,-1,-1,0],z,'b');
    fill3([1,0,0,1],[0,-1,-1,0],z,'y');
```

which has 2 parts,

- one for the first equation as a surface plot of $z=f(x_1,x_2)$ looking like an inverted roof, and
- one for the representation of the second (superimposed) constraint as another surface that can be considered as a "chimney" intersecting it (the underlying 2D curve with equation $|x_1|+|x_2|=1$ is the square with vertices $(1,0), \ (0,1), \ (-1,0), \ (0,-1)$).

Comment: Firstly, Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can I ask more questions? 1) I wrote equation wrongly on the question. I need abs(X1+2*X2)+abs(X1). So I changed codes, (Z=abs(X1+2*X2)+abs(X1); / f=@(x1,x2)(abs(x1+2*x2)+abs(x1));). But some part of 3D-line is not on surf. I think it should be included in the surf. Do you know why?

Comment: 2) I would like to know what "    x=[1,0,-1,0,1],y=[0,1,0,-1,0];" exactly means. As I understand , it's one way to give the contraint abs(x1)+abs(x2) = 1. But I don't exactly know how it is possible. can you give me more explanation?

Comment: I just discover your comments. Meanwhile, I have added somme sentences and - important - modified the picture by taking a larger scope so as to include all the planar faces of the figure. I am going to modify this figure for taking into account the forgotten factor $2$. Yes, this new factor has to be introduced in the function (that I should have called g) as well.

Comment: As you have seen, I have prefered to represent "in full" the second surface, panel by panel. I have abandoned here the intersection line which is always possible to draw afterwards with a little patience...

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation. I found it now and it made me more understand now. Thank you so much: